# Multiple classes getting the output of a parallel process performing heavy computations

Tags: python-3.x, object-oriented, multiprocessing

I have a python script with different classes performing various tasks. There is one class that performs heavy computations that are needed by other classes. I am using multiprocessing in order to do these computations in parallel and providing them to the other classes when available.

The Engine class is the process that performs the computations. The interface between this process and other classes is the class Interface.

So far, this is the code I wrote. The thing that is still missing is: since every result goes into the same output queue, how can I dispatch a given result to the correct caller?

A possible solution is the following: in the main process loop, the interface collects the results from the output queue and updates its internal state. Then, the callers access the interface variables.

Is my approach correct?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from random import random

class Engine(Process):

    def __init__(self,          
                input_q,
                output_q):

        Process.__init__(self)
        self.input_q = input_q
        self.output_q = output_q
        self.inner_var = 2

    def task1(self):
       # this task produces an output that is needed by the caller
       result = self.inner_var + 2
       self.output_q.put(result)

    def task2(self, param):
       # this task changes the internal state of the engine but does not produce an output that is immediately needed
       self.inner_var = param

    def run(self):
        commands = {'task1': self.task1, 'task2': self.task2}
        while True: 
            if not self.input_q.empty():
                req, data = self.input_q.get()
                if req in commands:
                    # call the method
                    if data is not None:
                        commands[req](*data)
                    else:
                        commands[req]()

class Interface(object):
    '''
    Interface between the engine and the other modules
    '''
    def __init__(self):

        self.cmd_q = Queue()
        self.ret_q = Queue()
        self.engine = Engine(self.cmd_q,
                             self.ret_q)
        self.engine.start()


    def task1(self):
        self.cmd_q.put('task1')

    def task2(self):
        self.cmd_q.put('task2')

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, interf):
        self.interf = interf

    def request_task(self):
        self.interf.task1()

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, interf):
        self.interf = interf

    def request_task(self):
        self.interf.task1()

interf = Interface()
# other classes
instance_a = ClassA(interf)
instance_b = ClassB(interf)

while True:
    if random() < 0.2:
        instance_a.request_task()
    if random() < 0.5:
        instance_a.request_task()
```

Comment: This code looks incomplete; in particular, the names `ClassA`, `ClassB`, `some_condition` and `other_condition` all look like placeholders hiding the real code.

Comment: @TobySpeight fixed with working example. I cannot show the real code, however this example contains all the relevant details